# iPhone Best way to handle modal view orientation change in main view?

Tags: iphone, modalviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have main view that presents modal view. When device orientation is changed in modal view, and modal view is dismissed controls in main view are not positioned properly. This all worked fine in iOS4, but now in iOS5 I have these problems.

What is best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewController's `-viewWillAppear:` method, call your layout method.
For me, this would be `-layoutViewsForInterfaceOrientation:` which I also call in `-willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:`.